# Mapping multiple XML elements in Excel

Tags: xml, excel, xsd

I am trying to map an XML file into an Excel worksheet to create a report. There will be multiple XML files all imported into a single Excel worksheet.

I have created an XSD file and I am able to map it to the Excel file and import data but the values are not mapping correctly in the Excel sheet.

Below is the XML sample file, all the files share this structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Task>
    <ID>13568133</ID>
    <Title>Sample</Title>
    <Description />
    <Status>InProgress</Status>
    <CreatedOn>Thu, 20 Feb 2014 15:41:21 GMT</CreatedOn>
    <Start>Tue, 25 Feb 2014 00:00:00 GMT</Start>
    <End />
    <CreatedBy>Joe Smith</CreatedBy>
    <Assignees>
        <Assignee>Bob Harry</Assignee>
    </Assignees>
    <Comments>
        <CreatedOn>Fri, 21 Feb 2014 15:28:56 GMT</CreatedOn>
        <CreatedBy>Person A</CreatedBy>
        <Comment>
  - Will they also be leading the P2P process during due diligence?
  - Robert has expressed concern around who will manage the P2P process
  - Robert to review IT Analyst Deck shared with his team earlier this month on 2/19</Comment>
        <CreatedOn>Wed, 05 Mar 2014 23:11:46 GMT</CreatedOn>
        <CreatedBy>Person B</CreatedBy>
        <Comment>- Complete initial onsite due diligence 3/3 to 3/5
- Mapped out current state process flows and initial validation confirmed by client
- Client may want to go live ahead of having CMD solution in place</Comment>
        <CreatedOn>Fri, 07 Mar 2014 22:17:31 GMT</CreatedOn>
        <CreatedBy>Person B</CreatedBy>
        <Comment>- Future state process flows in progress (15% completed)
- Tim  to contact client with clarification questions for future state
- Tim  to discuss process with client.</Comment>
        <CreatedOn>Tue, 11 Mar 2014 14:29:05 GMT</CreatedOn>
        <CreatedBy>Person B</CreatedBy>
        <Comment>- Future state process flows in progress (60% completed)
- Reviewed future state flows with the team on 2014-03-10, a number of questions resulted from the discussion and Tim will contact the client for clarification
- I sent my list of questions for the client on 2014-03-10</Comment>
        <CreatedOn>Thu, 13 Mar 2014 17:38:41 GMT</CreatedOn>
        <CreatedBy>Person B</CreatedBy>
        <Comment>Current state process maps sent to Tim for validation of process, future state process maps in progress (70% completed)</Comment>
        <CreatedOn>Thu, 20 Mar 2014 17:57:55 GMT</CreatedOn>
        <CreatedBy>Person B</CreatedBy>
        <Comment>Future state process maps in progress, 85% completed. Future state process maps continue to be validated and refined with the team.</Comment>
    </Comments>
    <Attachments />
</Task>
```

The trouble is that each comment and its CreatedOn and CreatedBy are in a single Comments block.

The XSD I was able to come up with is-

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element nillable="true" name="Task">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" name="Title" form="unqualified"></xsd:element>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" name="Description" form="unqualified"></xsd:element>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" name="Status" form="unqualified"></xsd:element>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" name="Assignees" form="unqualified"></xsd:element>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" name="Start" form="unqualified"></xsd:element>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" name="End" form="unqualified"></xsd:element>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true" name="Comments" form="unqualified">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:string" name="CreatedOn"></xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:string" name="CreatedBy"></xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:string" name="Comment"></xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

The trouble then is Excel maps the Comment, CreatedOn and CreatedBy onto different rows as shown in the screenshot. How can I make it so all these values are on the same row?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMXJ0.png

Thanks!
Joe